# Angular ngApp directive

Tags: angularjs

```
  <div ng-app="">
    <form>
      First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstname">
    </form>
    <h1>You entered: {{firstname}}</h1>
  </div>
```

The above code will fine. But if the ng-app="" directive if moved to form element then it won't work. Any idea why is this. Why the form element will not take ng-app directive and bootstrap the application.

```
   // This will not work
    <div>
    <form ng-app="">
       First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstname">
    </form>
    <h1>You entered: {{firstname}}</h1>
    </div>
```

Thanks

Comment: ng-app need to be top level. put in body tag

Answer (score 0):

`ng-app` is directive which is use to  initialize the application
so mostly it is used on `<body>` tag **or** main tag of application
Like :-

```
<body ng-app="myApp"></body>
```

**OR**

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
  <form>
     // add other elements
  </form>
</div>
```

So this type of directive is not applicable for child elements, even if you apply it will not work because by doing this app will not consider parent element so obviously child element also will not worked
In your case if you are using `<form>` tag on top level then you can use it like :-

```
<body>
  <form ng-app="myApp">
  </form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ideally ng-app should be at root level. but in your code, some part is outside the ng-app which angular don't take care of 
e.g.the h1 tag
you may write it within the form element or take ng-app to the root level

```js
<div>
    <form ng-app="">
       First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstname">
       
      <h1>You entered: {{firstname}}</h1> 
   </form>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It will work, the problem with that the `scope` of the app. You defined `ng-app` on `<form ng-app="">` so the scope is limited only to the start to end of the tag. Now you placed `<h1>You entered: {{firstname}}</h1>` outside the boundaries of `ng-app` so it won't work.

Check the working plnkr - http://plnkr.co/edit/zaTdGCouFrAXJywUSpcl?p=preview

```
<form ng-app="">
       First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstname">

       <h1>You entered: {{firstname}}</h1>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

From the docs for [ng-app](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngApp):

> Use this directive to auto-bootstrap an AngularJS application. The
>   ngApp directive designates the root element of the application and is
>   typically placed near the root element of the page - e.g. on the
>    or  tags.

In this code, the `ng-app` directive is at top level and the angular expression `{{firstname}}` will take its value from the model.

```
<div ng-app="">
    <form>
      First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstname">
    </form>
    <h1>You entered: {{firstname}}</h1>
</div>
```

In this code, the angular expression `{{firstname}}` can't resolve to its model since it lies out of the angular `ng-app`. Thus it acts simply as plain text.

```
<div>
    <form ng-app="">
       First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstname">
    </form>
    <h1>You entered: {{firstname}}</h1>
</div>
```